# C: Avoid indirection to refer to fields of struct inside struct

Tags: c, struct

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct inside {
    int insideMember;
} inside;

typedef struct outside {
    // magic goes here
    struct inside insideStruct;
} outside;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    outside x = {0};
    printf("%d\n", x.insideStruct.insideMember);
    // printf("%d\n", x.insideMember);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to alter the definition of `outside` so that the commented `printf` works (aka, I can access nested members directly).

I know I can paste in the definition of `inside`, to make `outside` have an anonymous struct as member, but in the real code `inside` has to go in a lot of other structs that need to have direct access, and I want to avoid to copypaste the entire block in each struct.

Comment: Does `inside` need to be named?

Comment: I need a named version of `inside`, yes, because I have to use it alone, as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `insideStruct`. Because in the duplicated question there's a solution that looks [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54542368e2ee07fb).

Comment: Yes, I've seen the other question and indeed it has the answer. That one is exactly the solution to my question, now I just have to decide if a macro looks better or worse than copypasting.

Comment: Personally, I feel a macro is the lesser evil in this particular case. Changing one definition and not the other is very likely when just copy-pasting.